# Find matches in 2 columns, compare data in third column with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, compare, multiple-columns, vlookup

I am hoping someone can help. I am comparing prices of products between a master sheet and a local sheet. I need to flag when the prices don't match. The master sheet contains all possible products but the local sheets do not, so first I need to match the products based on their product code and then based on that result, match the prices. VLookup didn't quite get me where I wanted to go, although I am open to suggestion, so I have tried my hand at the following code:

```
Sub match_price()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("master")

For Each i In ws1.Range("A2:A100")
    For Each C In ws2.Range("A2:A75")
        If i.Cells.Value = C.Cells.Value Then
        ws1.Range("C2:C10").Select
      End If
     Next C
    Next i
    For Each i In ws1.Range("C2:C100")
        For Each C In ws2.Range("C2:C75")
        If i.Cells.Value < C.Cells.Value Then
         i.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next C
    Next i
End Sub
```

However, my solution is not recognizing the differences, I suspect this is because it is not fully picking up that the differences should only be based on matched products. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT

```
SAMPLE DATA

Master Sheet

ID          Descrip     Invoice
14562738    A   119
25364058    B   245
26584024    C   375
67489542    D   19

Local Sheet
ID          Descrip Invoice
14562738    A   115
25364058    B   240
67489542    D   19
```

Edit 2: My resolution:

In case anyone is interested, I recorded a macro with my Vlookup code and added user2140261 conditional formatting for the flagging. I only wanted to highlight the text so I removed the coloring of the cell itself. I should mention that I need to use VBA as there are other types of calculations that I need to do across many cells and sheets, but user2140261 highlighting solution helped me take Vlookup to where I need to be. Thank you for your help!

```
Sub Macro()
'
'I always select D2 as the default active cell.
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],master,3,FALSE)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D10"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C2:C10").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
        Formula1:="=D2"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like exactly something VLookup SHOULD be able to do. Can you update your question with an example of what you have in your 2 sheets and then I think it should be possible to create a simple, formula-driven, solution.

Comment: @JohnBustos A formula can't highlight a cell, although a formula can add a value to a cell that a conditional format can be based off of.

Comment: I added in some sample data. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Master!A2:C5,3,FALSE)
```

Based on your Sample adjust ranges to suite. Enter this in Column D of the local worksheet and Drag down. Then to Highlight use Conditional Formatting where Value in C is < Value in D

Below Is a Copy of your Sample Data. On Worksheet Local.

[image: Sample]

In the picture you can see the VLOOKUP returns all values from the rows with matches.

TO highlight these values you will need to use a conditional Format:

[image: Sample2]

Notice in the SCreen shot that you must have ALL the data selected that you want highlighted. Then in the formula box enter

```
=D2
```

Make sure that If you try to click on cell D2 and the formula becomes `=$D$2` Then you ***MUST*** remove the Doller Signs (`$`)

And your final data will look like the following:

[image: Sample3]

Both `115` and `240` are red because they are less then the values taken from the Master sheet. And `19` is not because it is only equal to the value from Master sheet

From your edit to your question, I think you can shorten the macro a little bit, this will also speed it up a lot you should try to avoid using the select function whenever possible. Although there is a weird bug in VBA that no matter how you enter a cell reference in VBA it is always taken as a Row Column reference and never an actual reference. None the less this should clean up your example a tiny bit and also help with the speed if in the future you use this on a larger scale.

```
Sub Macro()
    Range("D2:D10").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],master,3,FALSE)"
    With Range("C2:C10")
        .Select
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
          Formula1:="=D2"
        .FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = -16383844
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer user, although I know how to use Vlookup. I am testing the conditional formatting now in a VBA format, will come back shortly.

Comment: @TracyPhillip Made an edit to my answer to reflect your recorded macro, to try and help it along.